Why does the Failed error occur when trying to send jetton NOT?
I have changed query_id and other parameters, but I always get the Failed error
Failed error screenshot
I tried it on javascript:
const receiver = 'UQBgyXy6AhPB_rVRaTlc40IFMSpAFm_KrQYzKNbKZzxoKGRA';
const sender = 'UQB3yamV4Zt69EqTigJDHPDt2pO_zeO7xxslihmCJUvtSGSt';

const body = beginCell()
        .storeUint(0xf8a7ea5, 32)                 // jetton transfer op code
        .storeUint(9875646865464364689, 64)                         // query_id:uint64
        .storeCoins(10000000000)                      // amount:(VarUInteger 16) -  Jetton amount for transfer (decimals = 6 - jUSDT, 9 - default)
        .storeAddress(Address.parse(receiver))  // destination:MsgAddress
        .storeAddress(Address.parse(sender))  // response_destination:MsgAddress
        .storeUint(0, 1)                          // custom_payload:(Maybe ^Cell)
        .storeCoins(8e6)                 // forward_ton_amount:(VarUInteger 16) - if >0, will send notification message
        .storeUint(0,1)                           // forward_payload:(Either Cell ^Cell)
        .endCell();

const base64 = body.toBoc().toString("base64");

const tonweb = new TonWeb();
const jettonMinter = new TonWeb.token.jetton.JettonMinter(tonweb.provider, { address: "EQAvlWFDxGF2lXm67y4yzC17wYKD9A0guwPkMs1gOsM__NOT" });
const address = await jettonMinter.getJettonWalletAddress(new TonWeb.utils.Address(sender));
let a = address.toString(true, true, true);

const transaction = {
    validUntil: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60, // 60 sec
    messages: [
        {
            address: a,
            amount: 8e6,
            payload: base64
        }
    ]
}

const result = await tonConnectUI.sendTransaction(transaction);

And I tried it on C#:
// Create a receiver address and the amount to send
Address receiver = new("UQBgyXy6AhPB_rVRaTlc40IFMSpAFm_KrQYzKNbKZzxoKGRA");
Address sender = new("UQB3yamV4Zt69EqTigJDHPDt2pO_zeO7xxslihmCJUvtSGSt");

// define jetton amount to send
Coins amount = new Coins(100); // for ex 100 jettons

Random random = new Random();
ulong randomUlong = (ulong)random.Next() | ((ulong)random.Next() << 32);
// create jetton transfer options
JettonTransferOptions options = new JettonTransferOptions()
{
    Amount = amount,
    Destination = receiver,
    QueryId = randomUlong
};

// create a message body for the jetton transfer
Cell jettonTransfer = JettonWallet.CreateTransferRequest(options);

// Create an array of messages to send
Message[] sendTons =
{
    new Message(
        sender,
        new("0.01"),
        payload: jettonTransfer),
};

// Set the valid until timestamp for the transaction (expiration time in seconds from the current moment)
long validUntil = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds() + 600;

// Create a SendTransactionRequest object
SendTransactionRequest transactionRequest = new SendTransactionRequest(sendTons, validUntil);

But I always get the Same error.
I have studied the documentation and made each line according to the documentation. I have already tried everything and I cannot understand why my transaction is not accepted by the network.

in c# version increase value in Message from 0.01 to 0.05
